# divide a disk image into smaller parts using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dmg

I would like to write a program that takes a .dmg file that is 1.6 GB and split it into 100 MB chunks.

I would like to also write another program that later can put everything back together so that it can be mounted and used.

I am very new to Python (and any type of programming language in general) and cannot find anything on here about this specific thing. Let me know if I am using incorrect terminology too so that I can learn how to search more effectively.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand exactly what's the problem you're having. Can you show us the code you already have? Stack Overflow members won't write your code for you.

Comment: I don't currently have any code. I mainly am looking for direction so that I can learn to do this myself. I definitely don't want someone to write the code for me.

Comment: No problem at all. Have you tried to search for any python library that handles DMG files?

Comment: Why do you need a library related to DMG files? When you split a file into chunks like this, it doesn't matter what the original file format is.

Comment: Just write a loop that reads 100MB into a variable, and each iteration writes to another output file.

Comment: On Unix you can use the `split` command, you don't need to write a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example:

**split.py**

```
import sys, os
kilobytes = 1024
megabytes = kilobytes * 1000
chunksize = int(1.4 * megabytes)                   

def split(fromfile, todir, chunksize=chunksize):
    if not os.path.exists(todir):
        os.mkdir(todir)
    else:
        for fname in os.listdir(todir):
            os.remove(os.path.join(todir, fname))
    partnum = 0
    input = open(fromfile, 'rb')
    while 1:
        chunk = input.read(chunksize)
        if not chunk: break
        partnum  = partnum+1
        filename = os.path.join(todir, ('part%04d' % partnum))
        fileobj  = open(filename, 'wb')
        fileobj.write(chunk)
        fileobj.close()
    input.close(  )
    assert partnum <= 9999
    return partnum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        parts = split('/Users/example/Desktop/SO/st/example.mp4', '/Users/example/Desktop/SO/st/new', 2000000) # 100000000 == 100 mb
    except:
        print('Error during split')
```

for join:

**join.py**

```
import os, sys
readsize = 1024

def join(fromdir, tofile):
    output = open(tofile, 'wb')
    parts  = os.listdir(fromdir)
    parts.sort(  )
    for filename in parts:
        filepath = os.path.join(fromdir, filename)
        fileobj  = open(filepath, 'rb')
        while 1:
            filebytes = fileobj.read(readsize)
            if not filebytes: break
            output.write(filebytes)
        fileobj.close(  )
    output.close(  )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        join('/Users/example/Desktop/SO/st/new', 'example_join.mp4')
    except:
        print('Error joining files:')
    else:
       print('Join complete!')
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! As I said, I am still learning and I just don't know what I don't know. I like to go through the examples that people post, learn what each piece does, then rewrite it without referencing to make sure that I understand it. I will give this a shot!